# Editing screenshots in iTunes Connect after iPhone app is in Pending Release

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm about to release an app on the iTunes Connect and I would like to change the screenshots. The problem is that the current status is Pending Developer Release. Is there a way that I can change the screen shots while it is in Pending Developer Release?

Comment: You needed to update the pictures before submitting the app update for review.

Comment: Ok, but what if I made some changes to pictures can I submit them now or after I release the app and why..

Comment: You can only update screenshots for a new app version before you actually submit the new version for review.

Comment: Ok, so only I make changes to the app is when I'm able to change the screenshots? I'm assuming it is cut down on the spam correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only edit / change your screenshots (app name, description, keywords) when the app is in an "editable" version: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW23

Mainly these are:

- Prepare for Submission
- Waiting for Review (Some are locked)
- Waiting for Export Compliance
- Rejected
- Metadata Rejected
- Developer Rejected
- Invalid Binary

You can either **reject your own approved version** or release it and **update it with a new version**.